# How to know status of process started with Win32::Job

Tags: perl, process

I have the following to start a process with a timeout

```
use Win32::Job;
my $job = Win32::Job->new;

# Run $command for $max_time
$job->spawn($Config{"C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe"}, $command, new_group);
$job->run($max_time);
$job_stat=$job->status;
print LOG "$command status $job_stat\n";
```

I read the [`Win32::Job`](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32%3a%3aJob) CPAN guide and added the last two lines because I would like to know whether the process ran to completion or was timed out. Is this the correct way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to find in `$Config{"C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe"}`, especially without a `use Config`

Comment: In this case, is `$job->spawn($Config{"C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe"}, $command, new_group);` equivalent to `$job->spawn($command, new_group);`?

Comment: I think if you look at `%Config` you will find there is no element with that key. The keys are generally simple aplhanumeric strings. The nearest is `$Config{sh}` which is `cmd /x /c` on my Windows system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://metacpan.org/module/Win32::Job), the `status` method returns a hash with two keys: `exitcode` and `time`. So if you want the exit code you should use it like this

```
my $job_stat = $job->status;
print "Exit code ", $job_stat->{exitcode}, "\n";
```

If you want the time used by the job you can use any or all of

```
$job_stat->{time}{user}
```

```
$job_stat->{time}{kernel}
```

```
$job_stat->{time}{elapsed}
```